# Cpp binary code JIT optimizations via recompiling parts based on of run-time information

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization, jit

Performance is very critical for my cpp application(an in-memory database). I have tried using JIT at runtime, meaning compiling and optimizing, the parts of vanilla cpp code, at runtime. The fresh compilation times from scratch are very non-deterministic and the overall gains are capped. It gives good performance though, but I am hoping I can extract out more,

My idea is if I start with some release/opt compiled binary equivalent at compile time and then optimize it at run-time, based on if data based optimizations are possible. Basically the performance of such a binary should be same as native binary when no JIT optimizations are done. If data is too large or if dynamic optimizations are possible, then I am willing to spend some time running the optimization passes on the build. Conceptually, here I will be saving the compilation cost of first pass on the code to convert it to runnable code module.

May be, I am talking at a high level, but it would make more sense when the first compilation pass is time consuming because of conversion of cpp text code to un-optimized machine code(as it would need lots of mem-allocations), and time taken by respective optimization passes is small as compared. Do you have any pointers or resources?

Comment: Please ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is rather open-ended... but it sounds as if you might want to look into [profile-guided optimisation](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToBuildWithPGO.html). Recompiling during runtime is possible but awfully difficult. For example, I've seen the compiler decide on different struct layouts (padding here rather than there), it would be rather a pain to have that happen when you already have allocated objects.